# How to boot into bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, infinix-hot-2

I have enabled USB debugging as well as OEM unlocking developer option in my Infinix x510 which is running Android 5.1.1. I [found that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm0Ak6fWrz8) to reboot into fastboot mode, I have to turn off the phone, then hold down both Volume Up and Power button at the same time.

In my case, when I follow the said key combination, the Infinix logo comes up, goes away then reappears, keeps doing so until I let go of the keys. It then follows the standard booting procedure and boots into Android OS.

How can I get into fastboot mode? I want to get into fastboot mode, flash TWRP, then via TWRP install the latest [Android OTA update](https://android.googleapis.com/packages/ota/infinix_infinixx510sprout_infinixx510/9393104c63b06172fc7078c01f4a9a586ffdc3aa.update.zip) manually.

Comment: What about `adb reboot bootloader`? And, why are you not trying to flash update file from stock recovery? You can simply sideload it, if required.

Comment: @Firelord Adb, fastboot none works. Side loading was the idea, but can't connect via any of those means

Comment: What happens when you execute `adb reboot bootloader`?

Comment: @Firelord Nothing. I don't expect `adb reboot bootloader ` to work when `adb devices` doesn't unless thats possible. The closest I've gotten at the moment is getting to fastboot mode upon restart. Tried unlocking bootloader, but didn't succeed although had OEM unlocking enabled under android debugging.

Comment: Then you need to troubleshoot why your device is not getting detected by ADB in PC. That's a separate thing to deal with. The command I told you would definitely work.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/hot-2/development/android-one-rom-recovery-twrp-root-sp-t3227682 My inablility to unlock bootloader is because a result of a known bug.

Comment: Since I'm on Ubuntu, this fixed my adb issues. Was using 1.0.31 instead of 1.0.32, yet didn't get any error message whatsoever. It was a protocol issue. Link: http://askubuntu.com/a/629243/101644